# Escreva função “contem” que nos diz se um array contém um determinado elemento

Tags: javascript

Escreva função “contem” que nos diz se um array contém um determinado elemento.

contem([1, 6, 7, 6], 7)
true
 contem([1, 6, 7, 6], 6)
true
 contem([], 7)
false
 contem([8, 5], 7)
false

Segue meu codigo porem da erro no ""contem([1, 8, 5], 7) é false""

function contem(elemento,numero){ 
  let array =[]; 
  for(var i=0; i< 3; i++){ 
   array = elemento.indexOf(i);

```
if(array!= -1)
{ 

  return true; 
}
```

} 
}

Comment: Caraca outra pergunta dessa?!

Comment: preciso muito de ajuda é para faculdade... se puder..